Post Correspondence Problem
I think this problem is unsolvable, if it is how do I do I prove it
Consider the following instance of Post Correspondence Problem (PCP). Is it possible to find a match? If YES, then give the dominos arrangement which will result in a match. If NO, then prove.
{[10/011],[1/0],[10/1],[0/101]  }
So far this is what I've done
my answer so far
